# Is there any way of knowing what Travel Modes are available for directions between two places in Google Maps v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

Is there any way of knowing what Travel Modes are available for directions between two places in Google Maps v3?

Of course, requesting directions for each travel mode and checking which ones return ZERO_RESULTS is a possibility, but it implies four http requests and four google api requests, which I'd very much like to avoid.

Comment: You have to ping the google servers to get a valid response like  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco&mode=bicycling

Comment: I don't think I understood your comment, @Mapperz